# C++ Best way to display image and hold it until the next image

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried using imshow in opencv to display a but the image window is closed and displayed again in every loop. Is there a way to hold the display until the new imshow arrives so the image display doesn't look flickering?

```
for(int iframe = 0; iframe < 10; iframe++)
{
..some processing code..
cv::imshow("image", a[iframes]);
cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

Comment: Only load the image if it changes?

Comment: the window shouldnt be closed unless you have some "closeAllWindowsBla' or similar in your code or close your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your ...some processing code...:

If you're using namedWindow() in the beginning of each loop **and/or** using destroyWindow() at the end of the loop, then you're effectively closing your window in each iteration.

Remove these function calls unless you're absolutely sure that you need them.

Comment: Thanks Saransh. I created the nameWindow before the loop and put imshow within the loop and it works. However if I have nameWindow in the main thread and call the imshow in the second thread, the window is created but the imshow command hangs. If I remove the nameWindow the image is display but then flickering (closing and reopening of the image) Any ideas? I can have this as a new question if necessary

Comment: I'll need some more details on your threading model ? Have you explicitly created a secondary thread ? and If so, what resources are the 2 threads sharing. imshow() might not be able to give you an output because when you're calling waitKey(), you're adding a delay on the main thread, but not the second thread, which is therefore running faster than the fps

Answer (score 1):

The two threads doesn't share any parameters except the display window.  Here is my code. I didn't include the processing part since it's quite long.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

// Some processings//

// Create the thread
cv::namedWindow("image2D");
std::thread t1(task1, "Start");
t1.join();
}

void task1(std::string msg)
{
std::cout  << "Task 1: " << msg << std::endl;    

// Some processings to compute img1

// Display img1
float min = -50;
float max = 100;
cv::Mat adjMap = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat img1;
float scale = 255.0 / (max - min);
zw.convertTo(adjMap, CV_8UC1, scale);
applyColorMap(adjMap, img1, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
cv::imshow("image2D", img1); // The code hangs here
cv::waitKey(1);
}
```